# Run command prompt in the background or in minimized mode using Java

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, processbuilder

I have written a code that executes a .bat file for me in cmd. However, the cmd window pops. I don't want the window to pop up, is there a way i can run it in the background or minimized mode using java. This is what I have.

```
 File dir = new File("C:/Users/SilverFox/IdeaProjects/scanapp_master/scanforcard/");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe",  "/C", "start","runthis.bat" );
        pb.directory(dir);
        Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bat` is a console script that requires a console window to run. You could run it minimized with `/MIN' flag (the console will only show up in the taskbar). If you need to run it totally invisible like a daemon you can try using the solution explained [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/131597/can-i-run-a-windows-batch-file-without-a-visible-command-prompt/).

Answer (score 0):

use call in place of start, see below

```
Process jmeter = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "call " + executionString});
jmeter.waitFor();
```

whereas `executionString` can be fairly long, for example below (trying to run jmeter with automated parameters)

```
C:\Workspace\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Workspace\Jmeter\jmx\my_request.jmx -l C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\csv_output\output.csv -e -o C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\html_output\ -JnoOfThreads=1 -JloopCount=1 -JrampUpPeriod=1 -JresLoc=C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\error_response\ -JaggrRprLoc=C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\aggregate_report\ -JsummryRprLoc=C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\summery_report\ -JresTreLoc=C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\tree_results\ -JbaseUrl=my-url -Jprotocal=https -Jport=null -Jbasic_token=mytoken -JtargetThroughput=240 -j C:\Workspace\Jmeter\results\2022_06_21_18_59_12\log\//jmeter_log.log
```